# Why can I add more lines to an Android Path object after I have already added it to an array?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I am working inside a custom view that extends View

I have an arraylist that holds a pair of Path and Paint

```
private lateinit var fingerPathForPair: Path
private lateinit var fingerPaintForPair:Paint
private var arrayListFingerPath = arrayListOf< Pair< Path, Paint > >()
```

Why is it that when I call the second line in the code snippet below (**which in my code is inside the View's touch listener in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` section**) I can still add lines to the `fingerPathForPair` such as when I use the code `fingerPathForPair.lineTo(touchPosX, touchPosY)` which is in my `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` part of the touch listener

```
fingerPathForPair  = Path()
arrayListFingerPath.add(Pair(fingerPathForPair, fingerPaintForPair))`
```

If you think posting my whole class would help you please ask and I'll post an edit.

### ADDITION 1

**Code to remove the last stroke the user made on the canvas**

```
fun undo()
{
    // Get paths from main finger paths array list and add it to the undo store
    if (this.arrayListFingerPath.isNotEmpty())

    {
        // Remove the last modified path from the main arraylist of finger paths and add it to the undo store
        this.arrayListFingerPathUndoStore.add(this.arrayListFingerPath.removeAt(this.arrayListFingerPath.lastIndex))
        invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you shouldn't be able to do that? The `fingerPathForPair` variable would still point to the same `Path` object. The only thing adding it to a `List` does is cause the `List` to have an element that points to that same `Path` object.

Comment: @MikeM. I was thinking that since I instantiate a new Path() object during the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` that that index in the array would contain a new Path object as if I had added it like `arrayListFingerPath.add(Pair(Path(), fingerPaintForPair))`

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood what you're asking. I thought you'd assumed that adding that `Path` to the `List` would prevent you from modifying that `Path` further. I'm not really sure what you're asking, now. Maybe we do need your whole class, and the details of what you're expecting versus what you're actually getting.

Comment: @MikeM. you're right about what I am asking. If I add a path to an arraylist how it possible to modify a specific Path in that arraylist without specifying which index contains the Path I want to modify?. 

I might be misunderstanding everything here. My program works how I want it to, I can undo previous user strokes by removing the last added Path() in the arraylist and re-drawing the canvas afterwards

Comment: Oh, OK. You're able to still access that `Path` – without having to go through the `List` – because the `fingerPathForPair` variable still points to it. Variables and objects aren't a one-to-one kinda thing. You can have multiple variables all pointing to the same object. Even though you add that `Path` to a `Pair`, and then to a `List`, that doesn't destroy `fingerPathForPair`'s "link" to it. It'll still point to that `Path` object until you assign it something different. Does that make sense? Am I anywhere close to what you mean?

Comment: But when I remove the last Path() from the arraylist why does it just remove the last stroke the user made and not all the strokes since `fingerPathForPair` points to the same Path() object. 
I will add my `undo` function code so you can see how I do this

Comment: Because they're separate `Path` instances, separate objects. Each `ACTION_DOWN`, you're creating a new object. When you remove one from the `List`, it doesn't affect the others. Also, `fingerPathForPair` doesn't _always_ point to the same object. You're reassigning it on each `ACTION_DOWN`, as well. It only points to a given object until you assign it a new one; i.e., until the next `ACTION_DOWN`. All the previous `Path` objects are already in your `List`, so they don't go anywhere, until you remove them.